# Double Values in listView cell

Tags: wpf, listview, celltemplate

I need to show old and new values in my ListView, when the record is changed.
I mean each cell should show new value and old value.
For now I'm doing so:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue}"/>
              <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding old.MyValue}"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

for next column it will be:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MySecondValue}"/>
              <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding old.MySecondValue}"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But I have 10  columns and this is not so interesting to make a lot of copy-paste for all 10 columns.

Any ideas how  this can be done more compact and more better?

The  ideal variant I want is something like this:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <MySpecialWhatever NewValueText="{Binding MyValue}" OldValueText="{Binding old.MyValue}" > 
         </MySpecialWhatever>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with custom UserControl like this.

**DoubleValuesCell.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.DoubleValuesCell"
             x:Name="root"
             ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewValue, ElementName=root}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding OldValue, ElementName=root}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**DoubleValuesCell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class DoubleValuesCell : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NewValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NewValue", typeof(object), typeof(DoubleValuesCell));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OldValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OldValue", typeof(object), typeof(DoubleValuesCell));

    public object NewValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(NewValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NewValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public object OldValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(OldValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OldValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public DoubleValuesCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**XXXWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.XXXWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        ...>
    ...
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:DoubleValuesCell NewValue="{Binding MyValue}" OldValue="{Binding old.MyValue}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    ...
</Window>
```

**UPDATE**

You can collapse second control with DataTrigger.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewValue, ElementName=root}"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Text="{Binding OldValue, ElementName=root}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OldValue, ElementName=root}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

The above code means the second TextBlock is collapsed if the binding source value (OldValue property) is null.

Comment: Thank you. It seems this is the only way. Although I hoped to use xaml only code, without c# and without creating new control.

Comment: Can I somehow use this class, if I want to use in one case -         TextBlock and in another case - Button?

Comment: I want to collapse second control, when there is no data in it.

I've added:

    public object OldValueVisibility
        {
            get {                
                return (OldValue == null) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; 
            }
            
        }
and bind to it like Visibility="{Binding OldValueVisibility}" , but it does not help

Comment: If you want to switch Control according to conditions, you can use DataTemplateSelector.